# How can I put space between href a tag and text

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI in React and trying to put space between <a tag and some text before and after,
at the moment there is no space and it merged to each other.

```
    <Typography style={{ fontSize: 14, textAlign: "justify" }}>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
      industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
      since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
      scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

      <a href={"https://www.lipsum.com/"}>Lorem Ipsum</a>

      It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
      electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
      popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
      containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
      Ipsum.
    </Typography>
```

Comment: How about adding CSS to the `a` tag such as `padding` or `margin`? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
 <Typography style={{ fontSize: 14, textAlign: "justify" }}>
<span >...your text<span>
<a style={{marginRight:"", marginLeft:"" }}></a>
<span >..your other text</span>
</Typography />
```